# React-bootstrap table not refreshed after axios call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, react-table, react-modal

I have a table that workig perfectly on page load, that page also include a modal component to update a line of the table, I'm using a custom hook to makes API calls and it works well.

The problem is after a line modification, I dont find the way to refresh the table. The DB get updated, the Toast shows the update success, the call for the new list is fired and got the new list in DBHook with console.log('Result', result) but, the useEffect with heats dependency never get fired.

If I go to another page and come back or do F5, the list refresh properly.

dbHook :

```html
export const useAxios = (url, method, data) => {
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState(undefined)
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(undefined)
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const params = {
        method: method,
        url: url,
        headers: { accept: '*/*' },
        data: data,
    }

    const fetchData = async (params) => {
        //console.log('in axios', method, url, data)
        try {
            const result = await axios.request(params)
            //console.log('Result', result)
            setResponseData(result.data)
            setStatus(result.status)
            //console.log('resultStatus', result.status)
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.response)
            //console.log('Error', error)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
            //console.log('axios finished', url)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(params)
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [url])
    return { responseData, error, loading, status }
}
```

Modal :

```html
export default function HeatModal({
    isShow,
    triggerModal,
    activeHeat,
    setActiveHeat,
    saveHeat,
}) {
    function save() {
        saveHeat()
        triggerModal()
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Modal show={isShow} onHide={triggerModal}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>{activeHeat.name}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form>
                        <FormGroup as={Row}>
                            <FormLabel column>
                                Nouvelle date de chaleur
                            </FormLabel>
                            <Col>
                                <MyDatePicker
                                    field={'date'}
                                    value={activeHeat.date}
                                    setter={setActiveHeat}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer as={NavContainer}>
                    <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={triggerModal}>
                        Annuler
                    </Button>

                    <Button variant="success" onClick={save}>
                        Confirmer
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}
```

List :

```html
const HeatList = () => {
const [heatsUrl, setHeatsUrl] = useState('/heats')
    const heat = {
        idHeat: -1,
        name: '',
        date: new Date(),
        idDog: -1,
    }
    const [heatsWithName, setHeatsWithNames] = useState([])
    const [heatPerPage, setHeatPerPage] = useState(10)
    const [firstHeat, setFirstHeat] = useState(0)
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    const [activeHeat, setActiveHeat] = useState(heat)
    const [editUrl, setEditUrl] = useState('')
    const {
        responseData: heats,
        loading: heatsIsLoading,
        error: heatsIsError,
    } = useAxios(heatsUrl, 'GET', null)
    const { responseData: dogs, loading: dogsIsLoading } = useAxios(
        '/dogs',
        'GET',
        null
    )
    const { responseData: editResponse, loading: editLoading } = useAxios(
        editUrl,
        'PUT',
        activeHeat
    )
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('activeHeat', activeHeat.idHeat)
        editResponse && console.log('editResponse', editResponse.idHeat)
        if (editResponse && activeHeat.idHeat === editResponse.idHeat) {
            console.log('in use Effect2')
            setActiveHeat(editResponse)
            toastSuccess(SAVE_SUCCESS)
            setHeatsUrl('/heats')
        } else if (editResponse === '') {
            console.log('in use Effect3')
            toastError(SAVE_ERROR)
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [editResponse])
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('in new heats array')
        let newHeatsArr = []
        if (heats && dogs) {
            console.log('in if', heats)
            heats.map((h) => newHeatsArr.push(buildHeat(h, true)))
        }
        setHeatsWithNames(newHeatsArr)
        console.log('newHeatsArray', newHeatsArr)
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [heats, dogs])
    const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(heatsWithName)
    const getClassNamesFor = (name) => {
        if (!sortConfig) {
            return
        }
        return sortConfig.key === name ? sortConfig.direction : undefined
    }
    const triggerModal = () => {
        setShowModal((prev) => !prev)
    }
    function buildHeat(origHeat, withName) {
        const newHeat = {
            idHeat: origHeat.idHeat,
            date: origHeat.date,
            idDog: origHeat.idDog,
        }
        if (withName) {
            let dogName =
                dogs && dogs.find((d) => d.idDog === origHeat.idDog).name
            Object.assign(newHeat, dogName && { name: dogName })
        }
        return newHeat
    }

    const modifyHeat = (h) => {
        setActiveHeat(h)
        triggerModal()
    }
    const saveHeat = () => {
        console.log('aH', activeHeat)
        setEditUrl('/heat/' + activeHeat.idHeat)
    }
    return (
        <Container>
            {heatsIsLoading || dogsIsLoading ? (
                <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
            ) : (
                <div className="table-container">
                    <h1 className="text-center">Liste des chaleurs</h1>
                    <HeatModal
                        isShow={showModal}
                        triggerModal={triggerModal}
                        activeHeat={activeHeat}
                        setActiveHeat={setActiveHeat}
                        saveHeat={saveHeat}
                    />
                    <Paginator
                        items={items}
                        dogPerPage={heatPerPage}
                        setDogPerPage={setHeatPerPage}
                        firstDog={firstHeat}
                        setFirstDog={setFirstHeat}
                    />
                    <Table
                        striped
                        bordered
                        hover
                        responsive
                        className="table-fixed"
                    >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <button
                                        type="buttton"
                                        onClick={() => requestSort('name')}
                                        className={getClassNamesFor('name')}
                                    >
                                        Nom
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <button
                                        type="buttton"
                                        onClick={() => requestSort('date')}
                                        className={getClassNamesFor('date')}
                                    >
                                        Date dernière chaleur
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {items &&
                                items
                                    .slice(
                                        firstHeat,
                                        Number(firstHeat) + Number(heatPerPage)
                                    )
                                    .map((heat) => (
                                        <tr key={heat.idHeat}>
                                            <td>{heat.name}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                {formatDate().format(
                                                    new Date(heat.date)
                                                )}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <Button className="noBackground noBorder">
                                                    <ActionLogoStyle
                                                        src={AddLogo}
                                                    />
                                                </Button>
                                                <Button
                                                    className="noBackground noBorder"
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        modifyHeat(heat)
                                                    }
                                                >
                                                    <ActionLogoStyle
                                                        src={ModifyLogo}
                                                    />
                                                </Button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </div>
            )}
        </Container>
    )
}

export default HeatList
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why have you disabled the exhaustive-deps rule in ESLint? Is it possible that the useEffect "is not firing" because you have not given it the full picture of what its dependencies should be? If you've done that because it was running every time (because the fetchData function will be created anew each time the hook is called), try moving the function into the useEffect callback or one of the other concepts described in [this excellent useEffect() post](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Brendan,

This is a real good post that helped me find the solution.

Final hooks :

```html
const dataFetchReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_INIT':
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
                isError: false,
            }
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                isError: false,
                data: action.payload,
            }
        case 'FETCH_FAILURE':
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                isError: true,
            }
        default:
            throw new Error()
    }
}

export const useAxios = (initialUrl, method, initialData) => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl)
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: initialData,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        let didCancel = false
        const params = {
            method: method,
            url: url,
            headers: { accept: '*/*' },
            data: initialData,
        }

        const fetchData = async (params) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' })
            console.log('in axios', method, url, params)
            try {
                const result = await axios(params)
                // console.log('result', result)
                if (!didCancel) {
                    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data })
                }
            } catch (error) {
                if (!didCancel) {
                    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE' })
                }
            }
        }
        url && fetchData(params)
        return () => {
            didCancel = true
        }
    }, [initialData, method, url])
    return [state, setUrl]
}
```

final Modal:

```html
export default function HeatModal({
    isShow,
    triggerModal,
    activeHeat,
    setActiveHeat,
    saveHeat,
}) {
    function save() {
        saveHeat()
        triggerModal()
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Modal show={isShow} onHide={triggerModal}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>{activeHeat.name}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form>
                        <FormGroup as={Row}>
                            <FormLabel column>
                                Nouvelle date de chaleur
                            </FormLabel>
                            <Col>
                                <MyDatePicker
                                    field={'date'}
                                    value={activeHeat.date}
                                    setter={setActiveHeat}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer as={NavContainer}>
                    <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={triggerModal}>
                        Annuler
                    </Button>

                    <Button variant="success" onClick={save}>
                        Confirmer
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}
```

final List:

```html
const HeatList = () => {
    const heat = {
        idHeat: -1,
        name: '',
        date: new Date(),
        idDog: -1,
    }
    const [heatsWithName, setHeatsWithNames] = useState([])
    const [heatPerPage, setHeatPerPage] = useState(10)
    const [firstHeat, setFirstHeat] = useState(0)
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    const [activeHeat, setActiveHeat] = useState(heat)
    const [heatToSave, setHeatToSave] = useState(undefined)
    const [{ data: dogs, isLoading: dogsIsLoading }] = useAxios(
        '/dogs',
        'GET',
        null
    )
    const [{ data: editResponse, isLoading: editLoading }, setEditUrl] =
        useAxios('', 'PUT', heatToSave)
    const [{ data: heats, isLoading: heatsIsLoading }] = useAxios(
        '/heats',
        'GET',
        editResponse
    )
    useEffect(() => {
        if (
            editResponse &&
            activeHeat.idHeat === editResponse.idHeat &&
            editResponse > 0
        ) {
            console.log('in use Effect2')
            toastSuccess(SAVE_SUCCESS)
        } else if (editResponse === '') {
            console.log('in use Effect3')
            toastError(SAVE_ERROR)
        }
    }, [activeHeat.idHeat, editResponse])
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('in new heats array', heats, 'dogs', dogs)
        let newHeatsArr = []
        let dogList = []
        if (heats && dogs && Array.isArray(heats)) {
            dogList = dogs
                .filter(({ gender }) => gender === 'Femelle')
                .filter(({ status }) => status === 'Élevage')
                .filter(({ state }) => state === 'Vivant')

            // console.log('in if', dogList)
            dogList.map((d) =>
                newHeatsArr.push({
                    idDog: d.idDog,
                    name: d.name,
                    idHeat: heats.find((h) => d.idDog === h.idDog)
                        ? heats.find((h) => d.idDog === h.idDog).idHeat
                        : -1,
                    date: heats.find((h) => d.idDog === h.idDog)
                        ? heats.find((h) => d.idDog === h.idDog).date
                        : 'Jamais',
                })
            )
        }
        setHeatsWithNames(newHeatsArr)
        console.log('newHeatsArray', newHeatsArr)
    }, [heats, dogs])
    const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(heatsWithName)
    const getClassNamesFor = (name) => {
        if (!sortConfig) {
            return
        }
        return sortConfig.key === name ? sortConfig.direction : undefined
    }
    const triggerModal = () => {
        setShowModal((prev) => !prev)
    }
    const modifyHeat = (h) => {
        setActiveHeat(h)
        triggerModal()
    }
    const saveHeat = () => {
        console.log('aH', activeHeat)
        setEditUrl('/heat/' + activeHeat.idHeat)
        setHeatToSave(activeHeat)
    }
    return (
        <Container>
            {heatsIsLoading || dogsIsLoading ? (
                <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
            ) : (
                <div className="table-container">
                    <h1 className="text-center">Liste des chaleurs</h1>
                    <HeatModal
                        isShow={showModal}
                        triggerModal={triggerModal}
                        activeHeat={activeHeat}
                        setActiveHeat={setActiveHeat}
                        saveHeat={saveHeat}
                    />
                    <Paginator
                        items={items}
                        dogPerPage={heatPerPage}
                        setDogPerPage={setHeatPerPage}
                        firstDog={firstHeat}
                        setFirstDog={setFirstHeat}
                    />
                    <Table
                        striped
                        bordered
                        hover
                        responsive
                        className="table-fixed"
                    >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <button
                                        type="buttton"
                                        onClick={() => requestSort('name')}
                                        className={getClassNamesFor('name')}
                                    >
                                        Nom
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <button
                                        type="buttton"
                                        onClick={() => requestSort('date')}
                                        className={getClassNamesFor('date')}
                                    >
                                        Date dernière chaleur
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {items &&
                                items
                                    .slice(
                                        firstHeat,
                                        Number(firstHeat) + Number(heatPerPage)
                                    )
                                    .map((heat) => (
                                        <tr key={heat.idDog}>
                                            <td>{heat.name}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                {heat.date === 'Jamais'
                                                    ? 'Jamais'
                                                    : formatDate().format(
                                                          new Date(heat.date)
                                                      )}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <Button className="noBackground noBorder">
                                                    <ActionLogoStyle
                                                        src={AddLogo}
                                                    />
                                                </Button>
                                                <Button
                                                    className="noBackground noBorder"
                                                    disabled={
                                                        heat.date === 'Jamais'
                                                    }
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        modifyHeat(heat)
                                                    }
                                                >
                                                    <ActionLogoStyle
                                                        src={ModifyLogo}
                                                    />
                                                </Button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </div>
            )}
        </Container>
    )
}

export default HeatList
```